# What is the best way to parse in dictionary? ios7

Tags: parsing, web, ios7, request, response

I got 2 types of response:

1.

```
{ Data =     {
    color = red;
    email = "may@mail.ru";
    number = 97;
    name = "john";
    dadname = "tim";
};
Message = "dada";
Result = OK;
```

2.

```
{
Data = "<null>";
Message = "Message";
Result = fail;
}
```

I need that left part(Data, Message, Result) be a key and right a value. And I also need that Data be a dictionary too. What is the best way to get this? 
For request I use AFNetworking 2.0

Comment: What is the format of the response you are receiving? JSON?

Comment: I think it http, because it has header